# pandas element wise operation for each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should be an easy question but I really couldn't find a similar one....
I'm trying to scale each column of a data frame by subtracting  the minimum of each column and divide by the scale. For R, I can do:

```
apply(df,0,function(x) (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
```

The data frame are integers only:

```
    col1 col2 col3
1.  20   32   14    
2.  15   33   67
3.  12   14   24
```

But pandas doesn't seem to do element wise division by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do something like

```
In [23]: (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
Out[23]:
    col1      col2      col3
1  1.000  0.947368  0.000000
2  0.375  1.000000  1.000000
3  0.000  0.000000  0.188679
```

Comment: Almost but I want to scale by the column minimum and column maximum.

Comment: That's what that does. All operations are by-column unless otherwise specified; for example, if you wanted to find the by-row minimum instead, you would use `df.min(axis=1)`.

Comment: @fuglede can you provide the row base ?

Comment: @Wen What do you mean by row base? I edited the comment above to provide an example of what to do if one wants to perform the same operation along the other axis, in case that's what you mean.

Comment: Right, I would probably find it more readable to just transpose the entire thing before and after if that's what you want.

Comment: Looks like some comments were removed above, so now the remaining ones make somewhat less sense.

Comment: how to add exception to certain column in this case?